# Spring data Mongo. Spatial Queries with @Query

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using a query in the repo.

findByStatusAndLocPtNear(String status, Point loc1, Distance dist1)

- How can I write this query with @Query annotation ?
- How can I  add another clause: findByStatusAndLocPtNear And name starts with A or B ? Is it possible to have AND and OR both in the method name ?

Comment: See these relevant Spring Data MongoDB topics: [Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries), [Geo-spatial Repository Queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.geo-spatial) and [MongoDB JSON based Query Methods and Field Restriction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-based).

Comment: The question is how to write findByStatusAndLocPtNear(String status, Point loc1, Distance dist1)  using @Query